# what does "-${2:-15}" in mean in bash?

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I saw this line in bash script

```
kill -${2:-15} `cat $1.pid`
```

It's killing process but don't know what `-${2:-15}` means.
Can anyone explain what it means?

Comment: Not an easy read the first time, but http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02 contains the answer ;-)  All you need to do is search for `:-`, it will take you to the definition. If you're going to have to debug existing code, then  you'll do well to understand what is contained there. Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

It means expand the positional parameter `$2`, or substitute with `15` if it is empty. So if the script is called with fewer than 2 arguments, the command will be:

```
kill -15 `cat $1.pid`
```

Comment: I believe the `:-` is part of the substitution syntax so it's actually `-15`

Answer (score 0):

The `<variable>:-<default>` syntax means "use `$<variable>` if it's defined. Otherwise, use `<default>`":

https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Parameters#Parameter_Expansion

In this case, `$2` is a positional parameter, or the second word you pass to the script. This code makes it optional -- if it's not used or empty it will default to the string `15`.

The `-15` flag sent to `kill` tells it the type of signal to send ... in this case `TERM` which should allow the process to quit gracefully.

For example, you could use:

```
script 123 9
```

This will send the `KILL` signal to `cat 123.pid`. I'm not sure what `123.pid` is, but it probably has the process ID of a known process you want to kill.

If you just did `script 123` it would send `TERM` instead.

Comment: Please don't link the ABS -- it's the W3Schools of bash, full of bad-practice examples and outdated information. Consider instead http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe, or https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Parameters#Parameter_Expansion, or https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html

Comment: (See http://wooledge.org/~greybot/meta/abs -- the record for the "abs" factoid for the freenode #bash channel; you'll note that the consensus has been that the ABS is a resource best avoided since that factoid's first revision in 2008).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy thanks, I didn't realize this